# Nothing happens when calling method from within SignalR3 rc1 vnext application

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

In my current setup, i have an ASP.NET 5 vNext project running.
I have setup SignalR Server 3.0.0-rc1-final and i am able to connect to my hub through my webinterface:

```
var visitorHub = $.connection.visitorsHub;

visitorHub.client.visitorEvent = function (message) {
   $("#visitorinfo").append("<li>" + message + "</li>");
};

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   visitorHub.invoke("listenToEvents", "TestID");
});
```

So we are listening on *visitorEvent* from the hub and visitorEvent is called when *listenToEvents* is invoked.

My challenge come now, that i'm trying to notify from within the ASP.NET application. Using the build in IoC an *SqlDependency* is used to listen to events in the SQL server. Again this is working as intended, but when i'm trying to invoke the hub through it's *HubContext* nothing happens.

I have injected the *IConnectionManager* and able to get hold of my *HubContext* using:

```
var context = this.manager.GetHubContext<VisitorsHub>();
```

but when i do the following:

```
context.Clients.All.visitorEvent("2");
```

nothing happens.

I'm not sure why nothing happens and how i'm going to debug this?

My VisitorHub code is:

```
public class VisitorsHub : Hub
{
    public async Task ListenToEvents(string visitorId)
    {
        this.NotifyVisitorListeners();
    }

    public void NotifyVisitorListeners()
    {
        this.Clients.All.visitorEvent("Event");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable client side logging via:

```
$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start();
```

or without generated proxy:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
connection.logging = true;
connection.start();
```

Otherwise when using `invoke` (method without a proxy), methods aren't renamed to camelCase, but remain as they are, in your case CamelCase.

To overcome this you can simply rename method name on either end, or add `HubMethodName` decorator in your backend:

```
[HubMethodName("listenToEvents")]
public async Task ListenToEvents(string visitorId)
{
    this.NotifyVisitorListeners();
}
```